# Проблема при позиционировании элементов

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Имеется блок с картинками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На фото есть значок просмотров в данному случае глазок, и я хочу добавить еще один показатель в правом углу картинки(часы), и вот когда я это делаю, у меня все обьекты смещиваются в кучу.
Вот так я делаю блок

```
<div class="video"><a href="watch.php?id='.$row[0].'"><span class="views"><span class="fa fa-eye"> '.$row[9].'</span></span><span class="time"><span class="fa fa-clock-o"> '.$row[9].'</span></span><div class="image" ><img src="https://thumbs-prod.si-cdn.com/P4Smi9MthEBXH7pdW8Y-bvwR6ts=/1072x720/filters:no_upscale()/https://public-media.si-cdn.com/filer/04/8e/048ed839-a581-48af-a0ae-fac6fec00948/gettyimages-168346757_web.jpg" class="image"></div><p>Desc</p></a></div>
```

Где класс .time это часы, а .views просмотры.

CSS

```
.time{
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.views {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.image {

    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}
```

Comment: float:left/right и absolute - для чего ? родителю видео сделайте relative и глаз и время absolute -глаз left 10px top 10px часы right 10px top 10px и всё и ели потребуется обоим иконкам z-index

Comment: вашим способом глаз ушел в шапку сайта((

Comment: разумеется  - у вас блок больше или relative не там где надо

Comment: .video {
 display: block;
 height: 40%;
 float: left;
 background: #34495e;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Параметры тени */
 padding: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 text-align: left;
 width: 24%;


}

Comment: вы сделайте пример который можно увидить в работе ..

Comment: я уже решил, добавил relative в .video,спасибо)